# Is grand canonical entropy extensive?

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose that we have a system that can be populated with either 0 or 1 particles. The system is connected to a reservoir and is able to exchange particles with it (i.e., we are in a grand-canonical situation). The grand-canonical partition function is then:

$$Z = 1 + e^{\mu\beta}$$

The probability of there being $n$ particles in the system is:

$$p_n = \frac{e^{\mu\beta \times n}}{1 + e^{\mu\beta}}$$

And the entropy is:

$$S = -k(p_0\times \ln(p_0) + p_1 \times \ln(p_1))=k\left(\ln(1+e^{\beta\mu})-\frac{\beta\mu e^{\beta\mu}}{1+e^{\beta\mu}}\right)$$

I am trying to extend this treatment to $N$ identical non-interacting systems as above and compute their total entropy. On one hand, I can simply use the fact that $S$ is extensive to multiply the whole thing by $N$:

$$S =Nk\left(\ln(1+e^{\beta\mu})-\frac{\beta\mu e^{\beta\mu}}{1+e^{\beta\mu}}\right)$$

On the other hand, I can rewrite the probability $p_n$ as:

$$p_n = \frac{\binom{N}{n}e^{\mu\beta \times n}}{Z}$$

Recompute $Z$ as:

$$Z = \sum{p_n}=(1 + e^{\mu\beta})^N$$

And rewrite $S$ as:

$$S = -k\sum\frac{\binom{N}{n}e^{\mu\beta \times n}}{(1 + e^{\mu\beta})^N}\ln\left(\frac{\binom{N}{n}e^{\mu\beta \times n}}{(1 + e^{\mu\beta})^N}\right)$$

I would expect these two expressions for $S$ to result in identical values, but they most certainly do not. Hence, one of the steps I took must be wrong, but I cannot see which one.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum in your final expression for $S$ should be taken over all individual microstates, not over values of $n$. The probability of a microstate $\gamma$ is given by
$$
p_\gamma = \frac{e^{\beta \mu n_\gamma}}{Z}
$$
where $n_\gamma$ is the number of particles in $\gamma$. Your $p_n$ is recovered as there are $\binom{N}{n}$ states $\gamma$ with $n_\gamma =n$. The expression for $Z = (1+e^{\beta\mu})^N$ is unchanged.

This gives $S$ as 
\begin{align}
S &= -k\sum_\gamma \frac{e^{\beta\mu n_\gamma}}{Z}\ln\left(\frac{e^{\beta\mu n_\gamma}}{Z}\right)\\
&=-k\sum_{n=0}^N\binom{N}{n} \frac{e^{\beta\mu n}}{(1+e^{\beta\mu})^N}\ln\left(\frac{e^{\beta\mu n}}{(1+e^{\beta\mu})^N}\right)
\end{align}
which is very close to your expression, but does not have the binomial coefficient inside the logarithm. Evaluating this sum gives your first expression for $S$
$$
S = Nk\left(\ln(1+e^{\beta\mu}) - \frac{\beta\mu e^{\beta\mu}}{1+e^{\beta\mu}}\right)
$$